# How to export auto-generated class diagram from VS 2012 to VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, reverse-engineering, class-diagram

Microsoft has removed class diagram generation from codes using reverse engineering.I want to move an auto-generated class diagram using VS2012 to VS2015 project but I didn't find a solution doing that.Saving generated class diagram in an .classdiagram file and then import that to another project will fail with error :

```
Cannot Load 'D:\...\ClassDiagram1.classdiagram': You must open this UML diagram inside the Visual Studio modeling project that was used to create it"
```

Any suggestion for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.I saved the complete UML project then open that in VS2015 and copy paste the class diagram to my VS2015 project.